# if $a, b$ and $c$ are positive real numbers such that $a+b+c=3\sqrt{3}$, how can we find possible integer values of $a \cdot b \cdot c$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How can we find possible integer values of $a \cdot b \cdot c$ when $a + b + c = 3\sqrt{3}$ for positive real numbers $a, b$ and $c$.

Comment: AM/GM inequality?

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to find real numbers $a$, $b$, $c$ such that $a+b+c=3\sqrt{3}$ and $abc$ is an integer?

Comment: Updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can set

$$a=\frac{k}{bc}$$

for some negative integer $k$ and $b,c\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$. Then

$$3\sqrt{3}=\frac{k}{bc}+b+c$$

This implies

$$c=\frac{\sqrt{\left(b^2-3 \sqrt{3} b\right)^2-4 b k}-b^2+3 \sqrt{3} b}{2 b}$$

(note that the discriminant is positive as $k<0$  while $b>0$). For any negative integer, the set of solutions are

$$a=\frac{2 k}{\sqrt{\left(b^2-3 \sqrt{3} b\right)^2-4 b k}-b^2+3 \sqrt{3} b}$$

$$b=b$$

$$c=\frac{\sqrt{\left(b^2-3 \sqrt{3} b\right)^2-4 b k}-b^2+3 \sqrt{3} b}{2 b}$$

where $b>0$. We can check that $c$ is non-zero (and that $a$ is well defined). Assume this is not the case. If $c=0$, then

$$\sqrt{\left(b^2-3 \sqrt{3} b\right)^2-4 b k}-b^2+3 \sqrt{3} b=0$$

$$\sqrt{\left(b^2-3 \sqrt{3} b\right)^2-4 b k}=b^2-3 \sqrt{3} b$$

$$b^4-6 \sqrt{3} b^3+27 b^2-4 b k=b^4-6 \sqrt{3} b^3+27 b^2$$

$$0=-4bk$$

However, since $k<0$, this implies $b=0$ which is a contradiction. We conclude $c\neq 0$. If you want $k$ to be a positive integer, then you get the same set of solutions except $b<0$. For $k=0$, you can set $a=0$ and then $c=3\sqrt{3}-b$ for any $b\in\mathbb{R}$.